# Australia: I'd love to build a budget urban bike on a budget, where can I find parts like frames and wheels at prices comparable to bike shop builds?

Tags: build

I would love to own a low maintenance functionality/comfort focused bike.

I am thinking:

- 8 speed internal hub
- belt driven
- relaxed geometry
- touring/cruiser handlebars
- pannier rack
- aluminium frame

This kind of bike doesn't exist in Australia - at least not for any less than $1500.

I'd be happy to pay that but I would die inside if it were stolen so I'm thinking if I build it myself I would spend less.

Looking on websites like Aliexpress, bike frames are suuuper expensive! How do companies like Reid and 99 Bikes sell bikes like the Harrier 3 and Pedal Pacer for $300 and make a profit!!

Comment: Is there a site like craigs list or e-bay in (your part of) Australia?

Comment: Building a bike yourself and is generally more expensive, than buing a similar specced bike. It only makes (financal) sense if your dream bike is not sold as you want or you already have parts laying around.

Comment: Components are cheaper if you buy them by thousands like bike manufacturers do.

Comment: Some, maybe even most, belt drives need special frames, which will reduce your options and increase your costs

Comment: @Willeke yes - gumtree and to some extent ebay are found in Australia

Answer (score 6):

I have done several builds with individual parts trying to beat the price of an assembled bike. It is difficult and time consuming. I was looking for fairly common parts, ten speed hubs, rim brakes, etc. I was fortunate that it was at a time that 11 speed drivetrains were coming out and the older 10 speed components were steeply discounted. In your case IG hubs are still a small part of the overall market share. Belt drive compounds the issue. There is nothing wrong with this design, but they represent a small segment. Small market share means fewer sources. This means fewer discounts are available. As other have stated the price difference between an assembled bike and the sum of individual parts cost is volume discounting. Looking at sites like Ali Express the price per unit between a single item and 500 unit lot is substantial.

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I find parts like frames and wheels at prices comparable to bike shop builds?

You can't. Even bike shops can't build bikes (in an apples to apples comparison) from parts as cheap as they can buy a complete bike.

If you want new the best way to get what you want is to buy a complete bike.
The biggest advantage to building a new bike from parts is that you can equip it exactly the way you want.

If you are OK with used you can get good deals.

If you can't find what you want used you might be able to start with a used donor bike and with some combination of used and new parts build what you want.

You want to go with belt drive and used belt drive bikes are less common than chain driven bikes so finding a used one might take some hunting. If you could go with a chain drive/derailleur system it will be easier to get a good used bike.